Why is H2 split heterolytically in the chemisorption on ZnO surface while it is split homolytically on Pt surface?
Read about homolytic and heterolytic dissociation of H2 on Pt and ZnO surface. What are the mechanisms that cause the different cleavage, what bonds are formed between the hydrogen atoms and the surfaces in the chemisorption and why is it important for hydrogen atoms to break heterolytically, in order to react with CO2 to produce methanol?

My speculation is that due local charges on ZnO surface, there happen H2 molecule polarization, leading to heterolytic split, similarly as addition of Br2 to C=C double bond.

Why do you state that $\ce{H2}$ is split heterolytically on $\ce{ZnO}$ ? How do you know this ? Anyway, $\ce{ZnO}$ has a polar structure and $\ce{Pt}$ has no polar structure. Pt surfaces do not creates polarization in their adsorbed symmetrical molecules.

"Read about homolytic and heterolytic dissociation of H2 on Pt and ZnO surface." In what reference?

It was in the textbook on Shriver & Atkins fifth edition inorganic chemistry when they talk about the properties of hydrogen
